# What are the variance and standard deviation for the bin counts for n rolls on a standard six-sided die?

Tags: standard-deviation, descriptive-statistics, discrete-data, dice

I'm having trouble imagining what variance and deviation mean with a series of die rolls.  That is, a fair die will fall with a flat distribution on all its values 1-6 in 6 bins (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6) over time (as n goes towards infinity).

Firstly, does the concept of *variance* really make sense on such a question? [Edit: only if I provide some data on bin outcomes.  Say n=36, and the die lands as follows:  1 (6 times), 2 (5x), 3 (5x), 4 (7x), 5 (7x), 6 (6x).]

The average outcome will be n/6 over time for each of the six bins  [Edit:  My prior writeup was confusing, as I had said the mean was 3.5 -- but this mean face-value is irrelevant to the question.]

Is this question even valid?  It seems a perfectly flat distribution (as n-> infinity), with no other hidden variables, *has no variance* (or *shouldn't* have any), but then what should one make of the results when n is finite?

Comment: This is a common routine-textbook-style question asked of students; as such it should probably be marked `self-study`; please see its [tag wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info)

Comment: "Dice" is plural; "die" is singular. From the wikipedia page on the [discrete uniform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_%28discrete%29) you can see that the variance for a discrete uniform on $1,...,k$ is $(k^2-1)/12 = (k+1)(k-1)/12$. When $k=6$, that's $35/12$.

Comment: @Glen_b actually Glen, I think it shows the weakness of the equations for variance--that there's no real model to make it less arbitrary.  To say that the variance is 2.916 when it's a fair die who's mean will always center around 3.5, who range is 1-6, and whose probability distribution is totally flat makes the result seem to some out of NOWHERE.

Comment: I'm sorry Marcos, I'm missing your point there; you may need to clarify what you see as problematic. i) Of course there's a model; the discrete uniform on 1,2,...,6. The calculation comes directly from the [definition of variance of a random variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Discrete_random_variable): $\text{Var}(X) = \sum_{i=1}^6 (i-\mu) . p(i)$ (where here $\mu$ is 3.5). The result doesn't "come out of nowhere", it's direct calculation from the definition. But the result for the general case (any number of faces, not just 6) is so simple that we can compute the general case...

Comment: ... and indeed, the even more general case (faces labeled not from 1 up, but from $a$ up) is also very easy, and is already available to be looked up on wikipedia. If you think it's "from nowhere" that can be solved by calculating it from the definition.

Comment: If my answer does not make sense to you, you might consider the case of a ["2-sided die"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_distribution) (I suggest to read the whole page, which is short and fairly clear).

Comment: @GeoMatt22:  I appreciate your attention on this.  My problem has to do with an information theoretic idea, namely that these answers output (i.e. give out) more Shannon-type information than is going into the problem.  So where are these extra bits of information coming from?

Comment: For a fair coin, $\Pr[x=0]=\Pr[x=1]=\frac{1}{2}$. Then $\mathbb{E}[x]=p_0(0)+p_1(1)=\frac{1}{2}$ and $\mathbb{E}[x^2]=p_0(0^2)+p_1(1^2)=\frac{1}{2}$. So $x$ has mean $\mu_x=\mathbb{E}[x]=\frac{1}{2}$ and variance $\sigma_x^2=\mathbb{E}[x^2]-\mathbb{E}[x]^2=\frac{1}{4}$. Similarly, defining the "information" to be $I=-\log_2p$, we have $I_0=I_1=1$ bit. So the random variable $x$ has an "entropy" (expected information) of $H[p[x]]=\mu_I=\mathbb{E}[I_x]=p_0I_0+p_1I_1=\frac{1}{2}(1)+\frac{1}{2}(1)=1$ bit. (The information has zero variance, $\sigma_I^2=0$, consistent with $H$ being maximized.)

Comment: *"That doesn't make sense: if the die starts at zero-based numbering, then the variance changes. But, variance shouldn't depend on the numbering of the die as all faces are equally probable. – Marcos
Dec 7, 2016 at 20:38"* It seems to me the variance is not the 'variance of the probability' of one side over another, but is the 'variance of the face values' from the throws.

Comment: Yeah, my question was conflating face value means with number of rolls that fall into bins (average n/6 for n rolls in each bin).  I reworded the question.

Answer (score 16):

While @dsaxton's answer is correct, I think it makes it more difficult for beginners in statistics to grasp the concept of variance, so I'll offer another answer that helps you get a better "feel" for the what the variance is actually "doing."  An equivalent expression for the variance in this case is:

$Var(X)$ =$ \sum_{i=1}^6(X_i-\bar{X})^2\over{6}$.

Now, you know the mean, $\bar{X}=3.5$, so you simply need to take the die's $i$th's face value $i=1, 2, . . . , 6$, $X_i$ and subtract it from the mean, square it, and divide it by 6.  In effect this gives you an average of how far away each die value is from its mean.  So $Var(X)$ is given by:

${(1-3.5)^2+(2-3.5)^2+(3-3.5)^2+(4-3.5)^2+(5-3.5)^2+(6-3.5)^2}\over{6}$= $17.5\over{6}$=$105/36$, the same answer @dsaxton provided.

We square the values of $X_i-\bar{X}$ because if we don't, then the sum of the values will add to zero and the negative numbers will cancel out the positive numbers.

Comment: Interesting.  Something seems arbitrary to me about it.  The result itself doesn't make much sense:  I know that with 100 rolls, the results will be centered around the mean and in a flat curve.  So to say that the results vary by 2.916 appears without any explanation of theoretical merit.

Comment: @Marcos What doesn't make sense about it?  It's just the definition of variance.  The sample mean of $100$ rolls *will* tend to be close to the distribution mean, but the variance is also reduced by a factor of $100$ so there's no issue.

Comment: @Marcos, the result is basically saying, that on average, the "squared distance between each value and the "center" of values is about 2.916.  There are other measures of variability that are used too, such as the mean absolute deviation which is calculated the same way, only instead of squaring the result the absolute value between each value and the mean is taken.  The variance has some important properties too.  For example, knowing it, you can calculate bounds on the the probability that a random variable is within a given distance of the mean, regardless of the shape of the distribution.

Comment: @dsaxton:  Thanks, I think I see my problem.  I'm used to 0-based reasoning.  Dice start at 1 and I think that throws everything out of balance in my head where I look for elegant results.

Comment: @StatsStudent:  then again (referring to prior comment), the roll of a fair die should be perfectly *flat*.  Flat curves have no variance.  To see the problem, try a 6-sided die that is numbered 0-5 and what does your equation suggest?

Comment: You're confused -- the height of the probability function is flat within its bounds, but it's not the probability at each outcome we calculate the variability of, it's the way the distributions of the *outcomes* vary. [You're seeing (1/6,1/6,1/6...) and thinking those don't vary but that's not the thing we're looking at varying. It's the distribution of *outcomes* --- the values (1,2...,6) all coming up equally often.

Comment: @Glen_b:  Still, given *infinite* die rolls the outcomes will be equal.  One has to treat this, I think, like one treats the limit theorem in calculus -- at some point, you have to take a leap of faith, because you can never get there --*yet* the conclusion is *sound* --each column containing each count will be equally high.

Comment: 1. don't confuse the outcomes (1 doesn't become more nearly equal to 6 as you increase the number of tosses -- 6-1=5 every time) with their frequency. 2. You're still misunderstanding what variance is. It isn't about comparing the heights of the pmf - i.e. probabilities (or even counts). That is something other than the variance of the original random variable, the variation in the *outcomes* the variable can take.  3. You're now also mistaken in thinking that in the limit as you toss a fair die repeatedly that the counts will tend to become more equal. ...

Comment: .... In fact the expected difference in *counts* increases in the limit  (but this variation is not directly connected with the variance of the original variable, which is what's under discussion).  While it is the case that the sample proportions will converge to equality, the counts diverge (their expected absolute deviation from each other will increase beyond any finite bound)

Comment: @StatsStudent:  you mentioned that the equation squares the values to ensure that you don't lose data (essentially), but you could also take the absolute value of the difference.

Comment: @Marcos, yes, you absolutely could take the absolute value of the difference, or use any other function does the same.  However, this wouldn't be the variance as traditionally defined, and using squares instead of absolute values, provides nice properties:  for example, squaring gives a continuous and differentiable function, as the take the absolute value is not differentiable at 0.  See my third comment above where I mention other possibilities.

Comment: @StatsStudent:  I think that absolute values is better.  Squaring the values amplifies the distance from the mean, but this misleads the person who wants to understand the data.  One small piece of data far away from the mean (an error perhaps) and it throws off the meaning of the variance to the data.  Also, if I have 10 data points around a mean of 1, say.  Some are below 1 and some are above it, squaring reduces the meaning of all data points between 0 and 1.  There's a discontinuity there as well where it starts amplifying again below 0.

Comment: @Marcos, I'm not sure what you mean by "better."  There are different criteria one can use to quantify a statistic as better or worse than another.  There are advantages to using the standard variance definition as I stated above, and there are other advantages to using the mean absolute deviation (MAD).  I don't think there is anything "misleading" since most of those working with variances understand its definition in squared units.  I'm not sure I understand your comment about values with a mean of around 1.  The variance is a differentiable everywhere, unlike the MAD.

Answer (score 7):

If $X$ is the value of the die we already know $\text{E}(X) = 21 / 6$ so we only need to find $\text{E}(X^2)$ since $\text{Var}(X) = \text{E}(X^2) - \text{E}(X)^2$.  We can just directly calculate

\begin{align}
\text{E}(X^2) &= \sum_{k=1}^{6} \frac{k^2}{6} \\
&= \frac{1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 + 4^2 + 5^2 + 6^2}{6} \\
&= \frac{91}{6}
\end{align}

which after some arithmetic gives us $\text{Var}(X) = 105 / 36$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but see my comment to StatsStudent below.

Comment: That doesn't make sense: if the die starts at zero-based numbering, then the variance changes.  But, variance shouldn't depend on the numbering of the die as all faces are equally probable.

Comment: My answer assumes we're talking about the kind of die we see in the real world, and I don't see how it doesn't make sense.  If we encounter one that is zero based then the first and second moments change accordingly so that the variance will stay the same.  If it makes you feel better apply the standard definition for the variance of a discrete uniform distribution.

Answer (score 6):

This is a discrete uniform distribution.  So we can use $\frac{(b-a+1)^2-1}{12}$ to solve for the variance. $\frac{(6-1+1)^2-1}{12}$ = $\frac{6^2-1}{12}$ = $\frac{35}{12}$

Answer (score 6):

There are already several good answers posted (as well as one in the comments). My goal here is *not* to replicate those answers, but rather to try and address an apparent confusion about the "definition of variance".

In your question you say

> It seems the variance and standard deviation tacitly ASSUME an a priori normal distribution around an unspecified or unknown order -- but a flat "curve" with no other hidden variables has no variance.

And in the answer you posted, you say

> The answer should be (ahem: is) 0. Apparently the equations for variance assume another unknown variable (another dimension) affecting results.

If we call the value of a die roll $x$, then the random variable $x$ will have a [discrete uniform distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_uniform_distribution). That is, if we denote the [probability mass function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_mass_function) (PMF) of $x$ by $p[k]\equiv\Pr[x=k]$, then we have $p[k]=\frac{1}{K}$, where $K$ is the number of distinct values $k$ can take (i.e. here $K=6$).

Independent of the *form* of the probability distribution, the mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$ are always defined in terms of [expectations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Univariate_discrete_random_variable.2C_finite_case). These definitions are
$$
\mu_x\equiv\mathbb{E}[x] \,,\, \sigma^2_x\equiv\mathbb{E}\left[(x-\mu_x)^2\right]
$$
(e.g. see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Definition)).

For a discrete random variable such as $x\in\{X_1,\ldots,X_K\}$ with PMF $p[X_k]\equiv\Pr[x=X_k]$, the expectation operator $\mathbb{E}[\,]$ is defined by
$$
\mathbb{E}\big[f[x]\big]\equiv\sum_{k=1}^Kf[X_k]p[X_k]
$$
where $f[\,]$ is any deterministic function.

Your confusion appears to be related to this last part. For the mean $\mu$ you appear to be correctly using $f[x]=x$. However, for the variance you appear to be using $f[x]=p[x]$, i.e. the PMF of $x$.

Perhaps the following summary will make things more clear

\begin{array} {c|c|c}
\text{object }(f) & \text{mean }(\mu_f) & \text{variance }(\sigma_f^2) \\
\hline
x & \frac{7}{2} & \frac{105}{36} \\
p[x] = \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6} & 0
\end{array}

In other words, the *probability distribution* $p[x]$ has zero variance, but the *die value* $x$ certainly has non-zero variance.